# What does \d+ mean in a regular expression?

Tags: regex

What does `\d+` mean in a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)?

Comment: Very good introduction: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 144, accepted):

`\d` is a digit (a character in the range `[0-9]`), and `+` means one or more times. Thus, `\d+` means *match one or more digits.*

For example, the string `"42"` is matched by the pattern `\d+`.

---

You can also find explanations for pieces of regular expressions like this using a tool like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) (online, free) or [Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/) (downloadable for Windows, free) that will let you enter a regular expression and sample text, then indicate what (if anything) matches the regex.  They also try to explain, in words, what the regular expression does.

Comment: But the `  \ ` is for escaping? am I right? thank you in advance

Comment: This answer is linked in [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419854)

Answer (score 30):

`\d` is called a character class and will match digits. It is equal to `[0-9]`.

`+` matches 1 or more occurrences of the character before.

So `\d+` means match 1 or more digits.

Answer (score 15):

`\d` means 'digit'. `+` means, '1 or more times'. So `\d+` means one or more digit. It will match `12` and `1`.

Answer (score 10):

\d is a digit, + is 1 or more, so a sequence of 1 or more digits