# How to use regexextract on an imported data?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, import

I can't get my regexextract to work properly on google sheets.
I have imported data from one tab to another, like this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o52z55YdNha4T_tCsKcHkrbA5sR4C1GyxYuBmMGGqu0/edit#gid=0"; "SheetName 1!A2:G103")
```

This works fine and what Im importing are percentages. Now, what I'm trying to do is to use regex to extract the numbers and omit the '%' symbol.
Normally I would  type: `=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A11,"\D+"))`but it doesn't work. However, if I use this exact Regex on any 'normal' cell (cell that is not an import from another tab), it works.

Is there a reasong regex doesn't work on an imported value?

Edit:

I have to send surveys to clients to know if they are satisfied with the provided service. Customers will choose between a few options. I do that using google forms by creating one form, and I link it to a google sheet where the answers from the form are pasted:

[image: Answers]

On the same sheet, I've added a tab where I import the data from the previous tab, by using importrange:

[image: Imported data]

As you can see, it works. But I want to take out the letters and the '%' symbol. I just want the numbers so I can run an AVG function.
Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I think it would be better if you could provide a sample sheet or at least screenshots of the sample input data and the desired output so that we can understand what's needed to help with the formula. At the moment I tested the URL above but the access is still restricted.

Comment: I just added some screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A11,"(\d+)")
```

Here is the sample input and output data using the previous function:

[image]

I think the problem is just related to the capital "D" since you need to use "d" instead.

You can check this other post as a reference:

- [What does \d+ mean in regular expression terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841550/what-does-d-mean-in-regular-expression-terms)